# Formatting for showing temperature at a particular time and date in en-US culture

Tags: c#, c#-7.3

I searched online and went through this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) site, as well but still could not figure out what the following format means. Could someone please explain with an example? I'm using `en-US culture` and latest version of C#.

```
string str = string.Format(“time: {0:t}, date: {1:dd/MM/yyyy}, temp: {2:N2}”, time,time, temperature);
```

**UPDATE**:

For example what 0 and 1 represents in {0:t} and {1:dd/MM/yyyy}?

Comment: What part doesn't make sense?

Comment: @Saruman Good question. I've added an UPDATE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this

[Format(String, Object[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object___)

And also this

[Composite Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> The .NET composite formatting feature takes a list of objects and a
>   composite format string as input. A composite format string consists
>   of fixed text intermixed with indexed placeholders, called format
>   items, that correspond to the objects in the list. The formatting
>   operation yields a result string that consists of the original fixed
>   text intermixed with the string representation of the objects in the
>   list.

The first number just corresponds to the index of param array of objects you are parsing at the end of the `Format`

```
0 = time
1 = time
2 = temperature
```

However this will probably make more sense with interpolation

```
$“time: {time:t}, date: {time:dd/MM/yyyy}, temp: {temperature:N2}”
```